# Date Picker: Any one day selection

Tags: datepicker

How to select any one day selection using datepicker.If user select in fromdate 05-11-2018 so todate also should be 05-11-2018.It means it will be only for one day data selection.
And all other dates should be disable.So user can select only one date.
Please help how to do that.

CODE:

```
 $("#searchFromDate").datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
    $("#searchFromDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date());

    $("#searchToDate").datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
    $("#searchToDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```js
    $("#searchFromDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $("#searchToDate" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
            $("#searchToDate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                   }});
   
    $("#searchFromDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
              
    $("#searchToDate").datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
    $("#searchToDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="datepicker" id="searchFromDate"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="datepicker" id="searchToDate"></p>
 
 
</body>
```

Comment: working..thanks...But my date picker is not loading second time..??

Comment: second time mean?

Comment: IN UI if page will change and again go the to page it will not load.After refreshing the page datepicker will load..